# Avoid duplicated code in script depending on sudo access

Tags: bash, shell-script, sudo

Is there a way to reduce duplicated code here?

```
if have_sudo_access; then
  echo "Installing system wide"
  FONTS_PATH="/usr/share/fonts/.local/share/fonts/"
  sudo mkdir -p "$FONTS_PATH"
  SauceCodePro="https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/blob/master/patched-fonts/SourceCodePro"
  sudo curl -L -o "$FONTS_PATH/Sauce Code Pro Nerd Font Regular.ttf" "$SauceCodePro/Regular/complete/Sauce%20Code%20Pro%20Nerd%20Font%20Complete.ttf"
  sudo curl -L -o "$FONTS_PATH/Sauce Code Pro Nerd Font Bold.ttf" "$SauceCodePro/Bold/complete/Sauce%20Code%20Pro%20Bold%20Nerd%20Font%20Complete.ttf"
  sudo curl -L -o "$FONTS_PATH/Sauce Code Pro Nerd Font Italic.ttf" "$SauceCodePro/Italic/complete/Sauce%20Code%20Pro%20Italic%20Nerd%20Font%20Complete.ttf"
else
  echo "Installing font for local user"
  FONTS_PATH="$HOME/.local/share/fonts/"
  mkdir -p "$FONTS_PATH"
  SauceCodePro="https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/blob/master/patched-fonts/SourceCodePro"
  curl -L -o "$FONTS_PATH/Sauce Code Pro Nerd Font Regular.ttf" "$SauceCodePro/Regular/complete/Sauce%20Code%20Pro%20Nerd%20Font%20Complete.ttf"
  curl -L -o "$FONTS_PATH/Sauce Code Pro Nerd Font Bold.ttf" "$SauceCodePro/Bold/complete/Sauce%20Code%20Pro%20Bold%20Nerd%20Font%20Complete.ttf"
  curl -L -o "$FONTS_PATH/Sauce Code Pro Nerd Font Italic.ttf" "$SauceCodePro/Italic/complete/Sauce%20Code%20Pro%20Italic%20Nerd%20Font%20Complete.ttf"
fi
```

I had thought of something like:

```
if have_sudo_access; then
  alias mysudo = "sudo "
else
  alias mysudo = ""
fi
```

And then use mysudo for all the commands that require sudo.

Comment: Why don't you check if `EUID` is 0 and if it's install fonts globally without running sudo which may possibly ask for a password?

Comment: Did your idea work?

Comment: I didn't test it, I was happy with terdon's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

## make a temp dir
tmpDir=$(mktemp -d)

## Download the files to it
SauceCodePro="https://github.com/ryanoasis/nerd-fonts/blob/master/patched-fonts/SourceCodePro"
curl -L -o "$tmpDir/Sauce Code Pro Nerd Font Regular.ttf" "$SauceCodePro/Regular/complete/Sauce%20Code%20Pro%20Nerd%20Font%20Complete.ttf"
curl -L -o "$tmpDir/Sauce Code Pro Nerd Font Bold.ttf"    "$SauceCodePro/Bold/complete/Sauce%20Code%20Pro%20Bold%20Nerd%20Font%20Complete.ttf"
curl -L -o "$tmpDir/Sauce Code Pro Nerd Font Italic.ttf"  "$SauceCodePro/Italic/complete/Sauce%20Code%20Pro%20Italic%20Nerd%20Font%20Complete.ttf"

## Check for sudo access using whatever "have_sudo_access" is supposed to be
if have_sudo_access; then
  echo "Installing system wide"
  sudo mkdir -p "/usr/share/fonts/.local/share/fonts/"
  sudo mv "$tmpDir"/* "/usr/share/fonts/.local/share/fonts/"
else
  echo "Installing font for local user"
  mkdir -p "$HOME/.local/share/fonts/"
  mv "$tmpDir"/* "$HOME/.local/share/fonts/"
fi

## delete the now empty tmp dir
rmdir "$tmpDir"
```